# Taking App data backup from Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

My Windows Phone app doesn't have a service hosted but I would like to give the user an option to download/backup all the information(Just say note taking app) to another device or PC. How can we do that? Email attachment is an option but is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

Realistically you need to be looking at creating your own service/server for this if you want to do it now. DropBox (or similar) may be an option but it requires the users to already have an account.

Or wait until the [Live SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264574.aspx) is available for the phone. (Or [apply for the beta](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=226223))

Comment: Thanks Matt. Do you think SkyDrive supports custom files to be stored there?

Comment: what do you mean by custom files? The web frontend for skydrive doesn't appear to place limits on file types.